# Spring boot request data from multiple endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a use-case were we have multiple existing API's with different data that needs to be merged into 1 single data object.

I was wondering if there is a solution for this in spring boot. Is calling the Spring 5 WebClient 5 times with different urls my only option, or is there a more simple solution?

Comment: Use webclient, zip/merge the answer into what you need.

Comment: Using `WebClient` would probably be the way I would go.  Using the various variations of the `zip` method should allow you to handle API's that can be called in parallel and those that must be called sequentially.